# Find if either followed by non number or end of file

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I want to match the string **b5** with optional **$** in front of the **b** or tha **5** :

```
=b5
b$5
= $b$5
($b5)
```

But  the **5** can't be followed by any number . And the **b** can't be preceded by any alphabet. So this should return false :

```
b55
ab5
```

I tried this :

```
\W\$*b\$*5\W
```

it works fine. i will match X=($b$5) but the problem is : it won't match anymore if the '5' is the last character in the line.

because 5 is last character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
(?:\W|^)\$*b\$*5(?:\W|$)
(?:\W|^)\$*b\$*5\b
```

See the [RE2 regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/r1VOND/1).

*Details*

- `(?:\W|^)` - a non-capturing group matching either a non-word char or start of string
- `\$*` - zero or more `$` chars
- `b` - a `b` char
- `\$*` - zero or more `$` chars
- `5` - a `5` char
- `(?:\W|$)` - a non-capturing group matching either a non-word char or end of string or
- `\b` - a word boundary.